# Update with values in other column in a single query?

Tags: mysql

I have a table tbl_a, with "ID" as a primary key, with columnns "A1","B1","A2","B2"

I'd like to make an update query that updates ID as:

A1 = B1 and A2 = B2

so that if the table was

```
ID| A1| A2| B1| B2  
-------------------
7 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 3
```

after the update:

```
ID| A1| A2| B1| B2
---------------
7 | 5 | 3 | 5 | 3
```

Is that possible to do on one query?

Comment: Your desired result is confusing.  First, you do not mean for ID to be updated (it stays the same), but you want A1 to be updated to match B1 and A2 to be updated to match B2?  If A1=A2 and B1=B2, your end row result would be 7 0 0 3 3, no?

Comment: I'd like to set A1 and A2 to equal to their B1 and B2 in row #7

Comment: Do you mean you want to SELECT the rows where A1 = B1 and A2=B2?  Your wording of the question is vague, since it never a good idea to alter the primary keys (if not impossible).

Comment: #Joachim Isaksson just answered below, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems as simple as

```
UPDATE table1 SET A1=B1, A2=B2;
```

Naturally if you want to do it for only the row with ID=7 you can do

```
UPDATE table1 SET A1=B1, A2=B2 WHERE ID=7;
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb1d8/2).